# display dynamic page using htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to redirect
http://testsite.com/campus.php
to
http://testsite.com/campus.php
but the file campus.php doesn't exists. It fetches the page content from database and it must be displayed.
I haven't got any idea.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but it looks like those two URLs are the same.

Comment: Please elaborate. Your 2 URLs are the same too. Take some time to write your question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Two URLs are same but I want to display the content from database using a common page. So the page campus.php doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your two URLs are the same.

But if you want to call a page that doesn't actually exist but is pulled from the database, you typically redirect some part of the URL to point into a `$_GET` variable used to access the database. All requests actually go to `index.php`, and `index.php` handles the database and displays the correct data.

```
# Conisde this pseudocode
# Rewrite somepage to index.php?pagename=somepage
RewriteRule /somepage.php /index.php?pagename=somepage


# The actual .htaccess rewrite looks like:
RewriteEngine On
# Assuming pagename is upper/lower letters and numbers only...
RewriteRule /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.php /index.php?pagename=$1
```

Now in your PHP, you use `$_GET['pagename']` (campus in your case, I think) to call the text from the database and display it.

**EDIT** I added the `\.php` to the RewriteRule.  Now `/campus.php` rewrites to `/index.php?pagename=campus`

Comment: You have understand the actual problem. I used your code but the following error occurs.The requested URL /campus.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @user738026  See the edit above.  I changed it to add the `.php` extension, which will rewrite campus.php into `$_GET['campus']`